# Alternatives to wsdl.exe for creating proxy classes from wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy-classes

[wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx), appears to be the default tool for .Net to generate proxy class from wsdl.  It [has known problems](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/06/bugs-in-wsdlexe.html) (see [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=470310) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=470482), also [some SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041765/webservice-unable-to-import-binding-from) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580042/c-web-service-client-multiple-web-service-methods-with-same-complex-return-ty)). Is there an alternative proxy class generator?

I am not doing WCF, so tools such as [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) may not be usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wsdl.exe is the only core .NET proxy generator other than svcutil.exe. If you want anything else, you'll need a third-party tool. Unfortunately, I don't know of one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but it came up in a recent search. I then found WSCF which is currently at https://github.com/WSCF/WSCF which may help people looking for something like this in future