# Error Consuming a RPC/Encoded SOAP web service in .NET

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-rpc-encoded

I am receiving the following error when calling a web service method.

**Cannot assign object of type System.Xml.XmlNode[] to an object of type System.String.**

The web service is a PHP service. I created my proxy class using wsdl.exe from the wsdl document defined here - http://webservice.intelecast.com.au/traffic/PublicSoap/server.php?wsdl

Below is the proxy client method I am calling.

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("http://webservice.intelecast.com.au/traffic/PublicSoap/server.php#getAllTraffic", RequestNamespace="http://webservice.intelecast.com.au/traffic/PublicSoap/server.php", ResponseNamespace="http://webservice.intelecast.com.au/traffic/PublicSoap/server.php")]
 [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("return")]
 public TmcInfo[] getAllTmcTraffic(string[] States, int[] EventCodes) {
     object[] results = this.Invoke("getAllTmcTraffic", new object[] { //Error here
                 States,
                 EventCodes});
```

It appear the proxy class is failing to deal with the complex types/arrays defined in the wsdl...I am unsure now how to proceed can't find a solution on the web anywhere.

Below is the SOAP response i am receiving. This all appears valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
       xmlns:tns="http://webservice.intelecast.com.au/traffic/PublicSoap/server.php">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getAllTrafficResponse 
            xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.intelecast.com.au/traffic/PublicSoap/server.php">
            <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:TrafficInfo[2]">
                <item xsi:type="tns:TrafficInfo">
                    <id xsi:type="xsd:string">1245632068110</id>
                    <entryDate xsi:type="xsd:datetime">22/06/2009 10:54:28</entryDate>
                    <direction xsi:type="xsd:int">0</direction>
                    <extent xsi:type="xsd:int">1</extent>
                    <locationCode xsi:type="xsd:int">31593</locationCode>
                    <countryCode xsi:type="xsd:int">4</countryCode>
                    <ltn xsi:type="xsd:int">56</ltn>
                    <diversionAdvice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</diversionAdvice>
                    <slAdvice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</slAdvice>
                    <quantifier xsi:type="xsd:int">0</quantifier>
                    <suppInfoCode xsi:type="xsd:int">0</suppInfoCode>
                    <addEvent xsi:type="xsd:int">0</addEvent>
                    <detDivAdvice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</detDivAdvice>
                    <destinations xsi:type="xsd:int">0</destinations>
                    <clSourceProblem xsi:type="xsd:int">0</clSourceProblem>
                    <eventCode xsi:type="xsd:int">802</eventCode>
                    <timeInfo xsi:type="tns:TimeInfo">
                        <start xsi:type="xsd:string">21/06/2009 14:00:00</start>
                        <finish xsi:type="xsd:string">05/11/2009 14:00:00</finish>
                        <timeZone xsi:type="xsd:string">Australia/Brisbane</timeZone>
                    </timeInfo>
                    <location xsi:type="tns:Point">
                        <lat xsi:type="xsd:float">-27.3112692120521</lat>
                        <lon xsi:type="xsd:float">153.029100894928</lon>
                    </location>
                    <additionalStreetInfo 
                      xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:AdditionalStreetInfo[1]">
                        <item xsi:type="tns:AdditionalStreetInfo">
                            <street xsi:type="xsd:string">Bracken Ridge Rd</street>
                            <type xsi:type="xsd:string">CROSS</type>
                        </item>
                    </additionalStreetInfo>
                    <address xsi:type="tns:Address">
                        <streetNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <streetName xsi:type="xsd:string">Bracken Ridge Rd</streetName>
                        <suburb xsi:type="xsd:string">Bracken Ridge</suburb>
                        <state xsi:type="xsd:string">QLD</state>
                    </address>
                </item>
                <item xsi:type="tns:TrafficInfo">
                    <id xsi:type="xsd:string">1245632111995</id>
                    <entryDate xsi:type="xsd:datetime">22/06/2009 10:55:11</entryDate>
                    <direction xsi:type="xsd:int">1</direction>
                    <extent xsi:type="xsd:int">1</extent>
                    <locationCode xsi:type="xsd:int">31592</locationCode>
                    <countryCode xsi:type="xsd:int">4</countryCode>
                    <ltn xsi:type="xsd:int">56</ltn>
                    <diversionAdvice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</diversionAdvice>
                    <slAdvice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</slAdvice>
                    <quantifier xsi:type="xsd:int">0</quantifier>
                    <suppInfoCode xsi:type="xsd:int">0</suppInfoCode>
                    <addEvent xsi:type="xsd:int">0</addEvent>
                    <detDivAdvice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</detDivAdvice>
                    <destinations xsi:type="xsd:int">0</destinations>
                    <clSourceProblem xsi:type="xsd:int">0</clSourceProblem>
                    <eventCode xsi:type="xsd:int">802</eventCode>
                    <timeInfo xsi:type="tns:TimeInfo">
                        <start xsi:type="xsd:string">21/06/2009 14:00:00</start>
                        <finish xsi:type="xsd:string">05/11/2009 14:00:00</finish>
                        <timeZone xsi:type="xsd:string">Australia/Brisbane</timeZone>
                    </timeInfo>
                    <location xsi:type="tns:Point">
                        <lat xsi:type="xsd:float">-27.3125370752656</lat>
                        <lon xsi:type="xsd:float">153.042898178101</lon>
                    </location>
                    <additionalStreetInfo 
                       xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:AdditionalStreetInfo[1]">
                        <item xsi:type="tns:AdditionalStreetInfo">
                            <street xsi:type="xsd:string">Bracken Ridge Rd</street>
                            <type xsi:type="xsd:string">CROSS</type>
                        </item>
                    </additionalStreetInfo>
                    <address xsi:type="tns:Address">
                        <streetNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <streetName xsi:type="xsd:string">Bracken Ridge Rd</streetName>
                        <suburb xsi:type="xsd:string">Bracken Ridge</suburb>
                        <state xsi:type="xsd:string">QLD</state>
                    </address>
                </item>
            </return>
        </ns1:getAllTrafficResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a bug in wsdl.exe? I have a few [unpleasant encounters with wsdl.exe](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/06/bugs-in-wsdlexe.html). Here are the problems outlined in my post:

> The first issue it fails to handle
>   sequence with complex element. You
>   would think that in today's webservice
>   environment, a sequence of complex
>   elements is a norm. But apparently
>   Microsoft doesn't think so, and this
>   results in inability of wsdl.exe to
>   handle a sequence of complex elements.
>
> What if you insist on using wsdl.exe
>   to generate proxy class for element
>   with a sequence of complex types? You
>   will get a cryptic exception: unable
>   to import binding * from namespace *
>   - unable to import operation *
>   - the datatype * is missing The second bug wsdl has is that it is not
>   permissible to have two web methods
>   that have the same return signature.
>   Yes, if one method returns a type of
>   ComplexType, the other methods must
>   have a different return type. Failing
>   to do so will result in an
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   XML element * from namespace *
>   references a references a method and a
>   type exception.
>
> Note that in both cases the messages
>   are cryptic. You won't actually know
>   what's going on behind the hood. And
>   this is the most frustrating of all.
>   You don't know whether you fail
>   because the tool is lousy, or because
>   you are not doing things right.

Maybe you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049839/alternatives-to-wsdl-exe-for-creating-proxy-classes-from-wsdl) for an alternative of wsdl.exe.

Comment: I think it may be similar to the first issue. It fails to handle certain complex elements. It could be more related to the  xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType type data in the SOAP envelope. I'm not using WCF, that other post didn't really help.

Comment: If this were the case then I afraid that you couldn't use wsdl.exe because MS doesn't plan to fix that bug

Comment: I've tried to implement this proxy consumer using WCF and I get the same error message. Interesting...

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that rpc/encoded SOAP implementation have problems on complex types. One way around this problem is to convert the WSDL to Document/Literal format.